# MySQL Replication - Tables with same name in a different DB

Tags: mysql

I have replication already set up, with replicate-do-db.
I have 5 schemas all with the same structure of tables - but different data of course.

I would like to replicate only selected tables from the schemas. Is it possible to just specify a table name in the replicate-do-table and it will replicate all tables with that name from all schemas?

For example, I have the following DBs and tables

```
A.test

B.test
```

And configure replication as follows

```
replicate-do-db=A;B

replicate-do-table=test
```

Will that replicate both tables? Or do I need to specify `replicate-do-table=A.test;B.test`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [replicate-wild-do-table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-wild-do-table) ?

Comment: how does that help me? i want to avoid specifying the db names. i want to replicate table 'test' from all db's (lets say i have a lot of db's and just want one table from all of them)